# How to make an automatic exit from the system after a token expires?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to somehow make an automatic logout if the token expired without refreshing the page? That is, let's say a person was on a site’s page, followed it, then closed the page or simply turned it off, then returned after an hour, and there a message was displayed stating that the exit occurred because the token expired. And at the same time, to display this message,  do not need to refresh the page or perform any actions on the site.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: this.auth.getToken()
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleAuthError(error)));
  }
  private handleAuthError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      this.auth.signOut(), this.router.navigate(["/sign-in"]), {
        queryParams: {
          sessionFailed: true
        }
      };
    }
    return throwError(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route guards for it. And this is example for it.

```
// src/app/auth/auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {}
  // ...
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // Check whether the token is expired and return
    // true or false
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
}

// src/app/auth/auth-guard.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

// src/app/app.routes.ts
import { Routes, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { 
  AuthGuardService as AuthGuard 
} from './auth/auth-guard.service';
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { 
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: You can add this `AuthGuard` in every route to block expired navigation

Comment: I did the same. Only for me, if the token has expired, the logs out after updating the page or performing any action.